# How can I vectorize a large number of subtractions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have one array (the "true" cartesian coordinates) which is of size `(natoms*3,1)` where `natoms` is the number of atoms. I also have a large number (500,000) of observations stored in an array of size `(nobs, natoms*3)`. Now, I want to create an array of the differences between all observations against the true coordinates. I would like to simply vectorize this by doing something like

```
for iat = 1:natoms
  xyz_dif = xyz_obs(:, 3*iat-2:3*iat) - xyz_true(3*iat-2:3*iat)
end
```

but this does not work. Instead I am forced to go through each of the observtions like so:

```
for iat = 1:natoms
  for iobs = 1:nobs
     xyz_diff(iobs, 3*iat-2:3*iat) = xyzs(iobs, 3*iat-2:3*iat) - xyz_true(3*iat-2:3*iat)
  end
end
```

but this seems quite inefficient. Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that xyz_obs(:, 3*iat-2:3*iat) is a matrix (2D matrix) while xyz_true(3*iat-2:3*iat) is a vector. You can use the function bsxfun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `bsxfun`

```
 xyz_diff = bsxfun(@minus, xyz_true', xyz_obs)
```

Answer (score 2):

an alternative solution, which in my view is more readable is to use matrix multiplication:

```
xyz_diff =  xyz_obs-ones(nobs,1)*xyz_true;
```